# Is there a way to pass the value of a model field as a parameter to models.ImageField(storage=function) within same Model

Tags: django, python-3.x, amazon-s3, django-models, django-model-field

```
class StorageModel(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="profile", null=False)
    file_meta = models.ImageField(storage=UserDataStorage(profile=user), blank=False, null=False)



class UserDataStorage(S3Boto3Storage):
    location = common.AWS_LOCATION_TEST
    file_overwrite = False

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        for k, v in kwargs.items():
            print("omg")
            print(v)

        super(UserDataStorage, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

How to pass the field `user` as an argument to the object `UserDataStorage`?

The problem here is, field `user` gets passed down to `UserDataStorage` but as a type `<django.db.models.fields.related.ForeignKey>`. I want a Profile instance here.

Is this achieveable in Django?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible the way you describe it. At this moment (when the code is initialized) the is no request/user objects to send.

What you can do is to pass a callable to the [upload_to](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.upload_to) kwarg as explained in the docs.

This way when the callable is executed, you will have the model instance being saved, and this instance have the user attribute.

```
def user_directory_path(instance, filename):
    # file will be uploaded to MEDIA_ROOT/user_<id>/<filename>
    return 'user_{0}/{1}'.format(instance.user.id, filename)


class StorageModel(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="profile", null=False)
    file_meta = models.ImageField(
        upload_to=user_directory_path,
        storage=UserDataStorage(), 
        blank=False, null=False
    )
```